# Odd warning aboud \label nameref

Tags: hyperref, debugging

I have absolutely no idea how this happened, but it is annoying me so much that I need to ask. Why does the message

> Package nameref Warning: The definition of \label has changed! Check your packages! Replacing it with the kernel definition on input line 145.

is always showing up to me? The packages I'm using are those below

```
\documentclass[english,brazil]{classified}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage[round, numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

The document class is classified because it is one that my university has developed, I've already checked the code and it does not redefine the \label in the kernel.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well if I use article instead of your class there is no warning. So your unknown class is doing it.

Comment: Write this in two places, one above the `\documentclass`, and one just below it: `\show\label`. If they are not the same, it means that your document class is the culprit. This can also be done for the other package inputs. Of course, the document class may not itself re-define `\label`, but it may load some package that does it.

Comment: MikTeX and others offer an update packages feature.  OTOH hyperref and presumably nameref (could be loaded by the document class) are dependent on \label and can be reloaded manually.